# about Intellij IDEA with clearcase

Tags: intellij-idea, clearcase

I'm a newer for IBM clearcase ,but for the reason of our company I must use it.
I want to use clearcase in my IDE Inlellij IDEA 12, so I download the clearcase Remote Client and enable the cc bundle in IDEA. when I start using the cc comand in IDEA, the errors come out :  the target clearright is not found . ---- sorry , the problem PC is in office.

what's reason?

I check my CCRC , the is no clearright command  in CMD ,just has rclearright command.
I doubt  the CCRC I have installed is not the right edtion ,is that right? if right, what edtion I should install. if not, what's reason?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, CCRC isn't yet supported by IntelliJ IDEA:

- the [plugin search](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=idea&search=ccrc) returns no result
- the [IDEABKL-5983](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5983) request for support is still open

The [ClearCase integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/clearcase.html) is for the full ClearCase only, not the web-based CCRC.

Comment: oh. it's history qustion..  only way is waiting IDEA support.